# Can someone in California record a phone call without consent?

Tags: california, wiretapping

Can I prosecute someone in California for secretly recording my conversation with them?

I had a private call and the woman is stating publicly she recorded it, though I had no knowledge of that at the time.  She lives in California.

Answer (score 3):

Secretly recording a person is a [crime in California](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=632): consent from all parties to the communication is required, and the maximum penalty is $2,500 and 1 year in prison. It does not matter whether to person has been convicted for some other crime (except that this could be a serious matter for a person out on parole). In addition, the person who is recorded can sue the person who did the recording. However, if there is a regular beep throughout the conversation (as specified in [California Public Utilities Commission General Order 107-B(II)(A)(5)](http://docs.cpuc.ca.gov/PUBLISHED/Graphics/567.PDF)), you have implicitly consented (you may not know that that is the meaning of the beep, but it is). The law provides for [civil action](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=637.2.) as well:

> (a) Any person who has been injured by a violation of this chapter may
>   bring an action against the person who committed the violation for the
>   greater of the following amounts:
>
> (1) Five thousand dollars ($5,000) per violation.
>
> (2) Three times the amount of actual damages, if any, sustained by the
>   plaintiff.

You (realistically, your attorney) need to show that you were damaged to recover from the defendant.

Comment: Thank you so much, my mind is more at ease now, regards